# Ruby: Inserting records to existing rails database using non-rails script

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that only allows users to search and view the contents of its (MySQL) database. To add records to the database, I'd like to run a ruby script automatically twice a day which generates the contents of the database and then updates the db. Is this possible, or does my script have to be a part of the rails web app?

Comment: Do you need to go through the app's models to do some INSERTs into MySQL or can you connect directly to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using rails runner command

Answer (score 2):

Just to lead you in the right direction - you can use a Rake task for this. These are usually put in the `lib/tasks` directory.

It's a good idea to separate non-web related things such as seeding or updating a database. If this is a scheduled job, you can use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to hook the rake task to cron.